# Calling pdo function with arguments

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to call this function with the argument of a table name, I have changed a number of things I'm not getting any output.

```
function getTbl($tablename)
{
    $mysqlConnection = getConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tablename;
    $Results = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);

    return $Results;
}

<?php 
  getTbl("college");
  echo Results();
?>
```

Comment: How do you expect the results to look like? `getTbl()` functions returns an object, not a string/array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your function return an object but you don't assign it.

try $results = getTbl("college");

Anyway you should ->fetch() or ->fetchAll() the object at some point, which returns an array and not an object

Answer (score 0):

if you are using [PDO::query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) do a foreach

```
function getTbl($tablename){
   $mysqlConnection = getConnection();
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tablename;
   $Results = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);

  return $Results;
}


<?php 
  $itens =  getTbl("college");


  foreach($itens as $item){
     echo $item['key'];
  }
?>
```